# Не получается переименовать файл

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.

Почему не работает в windows данная строка?

```
os.rename("newResource.txt", "oldResource.txt");
```

На ubuntu все прекрасно. А тут вот такая ошибка непонятная:

> File
> "C:\Users\����\Downloads\Request\ListElements.py",
> line 32, in CreateTxt
>     os.rename("newResource.txt",
> "oldResource.txt");
>
> WindowsError: [Error 183] ����������
> ������� ����,

Ошибка вроде как такова: "Не удается создать файл."

Comment: Вбейте в поисковике код ошибки, найдете текст ошибки в читаемом виде:

> WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

т.е. не удалось создать файл, т.к. файл уже существует.

Comment: @insolor, странно, а почему тогда на линуксе все работает?

Comment: может по той причине, что в линуксе регистр имеет значение, а в винде - нет. К примеру, в линуксе файлы "test.txt" и "Test.txt" - два разных. А в виндах - один и тот же.

Comment: @KoVadim, я тестил программу раз 20 сегодня и файл всегда там присутствовал. Просто не понимаю, всё вроде бы хорошо, но как только код перемещается на вин, то сразу: "сохраняй по другому", "это нельзя делать" и т.п. А много где читал, что на питоне код можно свободно копипастить с одной ос на другую

Comment: тоесть он как бы заменял существующий, а тут он вообще требует, чтобы его небыло

Comment: > А много где читал, что на питоне код можно свободно копипастить с одной ос на другую

Вы тянете модуль **os**. Какова вероятность того, что он будет работать абсолютно одинаково? Какова вероятность того, что он сам по себе не задумывается о существовании файла, а тянет функцию ОС?

Да, копировать можно. Если проводить необходимые проверки и пользоваться всякими `os.path.join` (я поэтому даже не знаю, как в питоне на винде с прямыми слешами в пути). А у вас функция **переименования** пытается переименовать файл в другой, уже существующий. Наоборот, странно что на убунте это работает.

Comment: @artemiy
> А много где читал, что на питоне код можно свободно копипастить с одной ос на другую

Вот только на днях тестил программу на java (где где, а в java с кросплатформенностью стараются). И она пыталась создать файл с именем "~/logs". да, именно таким именем, с слешем и тильдой. Более того, ей это удалось.

Кроссплатформенность есть в многих языком. Но в большинстве случаев она достигается ручками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Читайте [документацию](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename), там все написано:

> Rename the file or directory src to
> dst. If dst is a directory, OSError
> will be raised. **On Unix, if dst exists
> and is a file, it will be replaced
> silently if the user has permission**.
> The operation may fail on some Unix
> flavors if src and dst are on
> different filesystems. If successful,
> the renaming will be an atomic
> operation (this is a POSIX
> requirement). **On Windows, if dst
> already exists, OSError will be raised
> even if it is a file**; there may be no
> way to implement an atomic rename when
> dst names an existing file.

Получается под Windows может не быть атомарного move, и разроботчики CPython переложили ответственность за проверку существования `dst` на пользователей. Если честно, не очень понимаю, как в таком случае правильно делать move, ведь между проверкой на то, что файл существует, и вызовом rename кто-то может создать файл.

Comment: можно [`os.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) использовать, если `dst` уже существует.